# How to add using jquery `a href` for label?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="id_zip_code">
      Zip code:
</label>
```

How to add using jquery `a href` for this label?

Excepted output:

```
<a href="http://google.com"><label for="id_zip_code">Zip code:</label></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('label[for="id_zip_code"]').wrap('<a href="http://google.com"><a/>')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('label[for=id_zip_code]').wrap($('<a />', {href: "http://google.com"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wrap()`:

```
 $('label').wrap($('<a></a>', {
     'href': 'http://www.google.com'
 });
```

Obviously, you'd be best to make the `label` selector more specific by adding a class or id to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [**wrapInner**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
<label id="somelable" for="id_zip_code">
      Zip code:
</label>


$("#somelable").wrapInner("<a href=http://google.com></a>");
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1477/)